# How can I display string elements received by json based on the date and time they should be displayed?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a database and I store there a text, its duration and time when it should appear on the webpage.

The result of the php is as follows:

```
{"text_content":"dgsgdsgds","text_duration":"15","start_time":"2015-09-28 23:11:15"},{"text_content":"dgsgdsgds","text_duration":"15","start_time":"2015-09-28 23:11:30"},{"text_content":"gdsgdsgds","text_duration":"15","start_time":"2015-10-01 14:00:00"}
```

I have a jquery script that fetches the data from the database and prints it on the screen:

```
var results =[];
var cursor = 0;

function myFunction () {
    $.getJSON('list2.php', function(json) {
        results = json;
        cursor = 0;

        // Now start printing
        printNext();
    });
}

function printNext(){
    if(cursor == results.length){
        // Reset the cursor back to the beginning.
        cursor = 0;
    }

    // Print the key1 in the div.
    //$('#mydiv').html(results[cursor].key1);
    $('#mydiv').hide('fast', function(){ $('#mydiv').html(results[cursor].text_content); $('#mydiv').show('fast'); });

    // Set a delay for the current item to stay
    // Delay is key2 * 1000 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        printNext();
    }, results[cursor].text_duration * 1000);

    // Advance the cursor.
    cursor++;
}
```

and now I wanted to add a feature that text displays on the screen only on a date that is fetched from database, as `start_time`, but I'm not sure if it's possible to do on jquery only, without any further access to the server code..
I tried adding some if statement like:

```
if(results[cursor].start_time == new Date()){
```

just before printing it on the screen but it didn't do the trick. Could you help me with that?
Thanks!

Comment: better fetch only the required data based on time from DB. @randomuser1

Comment: I thought about that but I want to do a recurrent query that fetches data for each hour and then displays the data according to the minutes of that hour..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse your json string with `JSON.parse`:

```
var myObj = JSON.parse(results[0]);
```

and compare your `start_time`:

```
if (new Date(myObj.start_time) == new Date())
```

if you want run your function on specific time use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
var diff = new Date(myObj.start_time).getTime() - new Date().getTime();
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#mydiv').hide('fast', function() {
        $('#mydiv').html(results[cursor].text_content);
        $('#mydiv').show('fast');
    });
}, diff)
```

or you can execute your function every 1000ms by using `setInterval` and stop it with `clearInterval`:

```
function check() {
    if (new Date(myObj.start_time) == new Date()) {
        $('#mydiv').hide('fast', function() {
            $('#mydiv').html(results[cursor].text_content);
            $('#mydiv').show('fast');
        });
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
}

var myInterval = setInterval(check, 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks @kakajan, however one more thing - I just figured it out that even if I check this condition before this line: `$('#mydiv').hide('fast', function(){ $('#mydiv').html(results[cursor].text_content); $('#mydiv').show('fast'); });
` then it will be checked only once and if the date is different even for one second then I will never display my text on screen. Is there a way of somehow preventing it, like looping every second and checking if there's some available text to display?

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your answer and this is what I need! I just have one question - could you briefly explain me why do you put `new Date(myObj.start_time)` as a second parameter to the setTimeout method (the same with setInterval)? shouldn't there be some numeric value instead?

Comment: The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds. So, i have an error there, i updated answer, we must calculate difference of time from now date. Here is explanation of [setTimeOut](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much, I believe the same situation is for the setInterval at the very end?

Comment: Yes same for both, but second parameter is number of milliseconds to wait before executing the code. So i updated answer again, diff is calculated is milliseconds.